# ¿Cómo hacer que rote el icono de google o de font awesome al hacer click?

Tags: javascript, html, css

que cambie o rote el icono al hacer click cono animación o sin animación[image: que cambie o rote el icono al hacer click cono animación o sin animación]

Comment: Hola se puede hacer hasta sin javascript, pero debe modificar tu pregunta e insertar tu código HTML y CSS si quieres que alguien te ayude.

Comment: Puedes incluir tu código html para poder tener una referencia mas adecuada

Answer (score 1):

Si no quieres animación puedes hacer esto

```js
//Coges la imagen de la web
document.getElementById("h1").addEventListener('click', function() {
//Cambias su src a otro nuevo
document.getElementById("img").src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ef/Stack_Overflow_icon.svg/768px-Stack_Overflow_icon.svg.png" //Imagen nueva
})
```

```css
h1
{
background: #03e9f4;
padding: 12px;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="h1">PULSA AQUÍ</h1>
<img src="https://rmggames.web.app/logo-192.png" id="img">
```

Si lo quieres con animación puedes utilizar las animaciones de Js tutorial aquí: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_animate.asp

Comment: Buenas bro, cuando alguien no ha presentado el codigo, es buena idea no hacerles la tarea o trabajo, por que o no lo han hecho, o no tienen idea de lo que hacen. Ideal es esperar a que responda al menos con codigo, no con imagen como hicieron acá.

Comment: Lo tendré en cuenta para futuras respuestas.

Comment: Exacto, la idea no es que no ayudes o no respondas y obtengas tu puntaje. Sino, el no estar haciendo la tarea de alguien que no sabemos si ha hecho o no algo, y si entiende lo que esta haciendo o no. Por que yo copio y pego y ah.. me sirve, nunca mas te responde... en este caso van 3 horas, y no hay update del post.

Answer (score 0):

Podes agregarle una clase cuando le haces click al H1, como `.activo { transform: rotate(180deg); }`;

Entonces cada vez que se le hace click, el icono gira 180 grados.

```
document.getElementById('h1').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('icon').classList.toggle('active');
})
```

Comment: Buenas bro, cuando alguien no ha presentado el codigo, es buena idea no hacerles la tarea o trabajo, por que o no lo han hecho, o no tienen idea de lo que hacen. Ideal es esperar a que responda al menos con codigo, no con imagen como hicieron acá.

Comment: Hola.... Bien, gracias por tu comentario... Ahora lo elimino para no quedar mal... Como verás soy nuevo en esto y tu comentario me ayuda mucho.

Comment: No es necesario borrarlo, es un dato, para que no hagas trabajos de otros.

Comment: Bien, Gracias!!!